# Multiple nth-last-child and/or last-child not working

Tags: css, css-selectors

**NOT WORKING:**

```
td:not(:last-child), td:not(:nth-last-child(2))
{ background-color:#ccc; }
```

**NOT WORKING:**

```
td:not(:nth-last-child(1)), td:not(:nth-last-child(2))
{ background-color:#ccc; }
```

**NOT WORKING:**

```
td:not(:nth-last-child(2))
{ background-color:#ccc; }

td:not(:nth-last-child(1))
{ background-color:#ccc; }
```

**WORKS WHEN ALONE:**

```
td:not(:nth-last-child(2))
{ background-color:#ccc; }
```

**WORKS WHEN ALONE**

```
td:not(:nth-last-child(1))
{ background-color:#ccc; }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/HBeRH/

Comment: OK... so what's your question?

Comment: Please provide your markup too, preferably along with appropriate styles in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.com)

Comment: The question is that I'm trying to make multiple nth-last-child work. @blend, I added a fiddle.

Comment: @NaturalBornCamper: That's a statement, not a question. The fiddle doesn't really help explain anything either. You're lucky techfoobar was able to figure out exactly what you were looking for (possibly from your comment), but you'll be hard-pressed to find answers if all you say is what works and what doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
td:not(:nth-last-child(2)):not(:nth-last-child(1)) {
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```

**[Check this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HBeRH/2/)**

Comment: Great thanks! I knew there was a way of writing that in a cleaner way, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there are 4 children, as in your fiddle, numbered 1-4.

`td:not(:last-child)` refers to tds 1, 2, and 3. `td:not(:nth-last-child(2))` refers to tds 1, 2, and 4. So when you have both styles in your stylesheet, they apply the style to all 4 tds, because td 3 is included in the first one, and td 4 is included in the second one.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of these is the following:

`td:not(:nth-last-child(2))
{ background-color:#ccc; }`

the statement means that all the elements must have background **except third element** and

```
td:not(:nth-last-child(1))
{ background-color:#ccc; }
```

the statement means that all the elements must have background **except fourth element**.

its logical that all of them have background

**You can use this code. here is the working code**
http://jsfiddle.net/DeQ6K/